# how to access the key in json object in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, mern

I am getting the object below its in json form. i wanted to access only user key from the below object.  I tried destructuring the object but didnt got expected value;

```
  const logg=window.localStorage.getItem("userInfo");
 const {user}=logg;
 console.log(user);
console.log(logg.user);
console.log(logg);
```

[image]

```
{"success":true,"user":{"avatar":{"public_id":"avatars/laqmzy3nuqa5vl7awprh","url":"https://res.cloudinary.com/randomID/image/upload/v1659523730/avatars/laqmzy3nuqa5vl7awprh.jpg"},"_id":"62ea5294ff799046c8173fef","name":"sumit khatri","email":"ss@sss.com","password":"$2a$10$nSK2JqUSCdVGIVVBzo1IDerU3jrNFfHRDBESV0Ql6y.vWohZiugEG","role":"admin","createdAt":"2022-08-03T10:48:52.355Z","__v":0},"token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYyZWE1Mjk0ZmY3OTkwNDZjODE3M2ZlZiIsImlhdCI6MTY1OTUyNzM1NCwiZXhwIjoxNjU5OTU5MzU0fQ.TLJYRAm83qQuLVhVkIqYK0u7WetCm9Hn376VvEPX1Ig"}
```

Comment: There is no user "key". Did you mean `_id`?

Comment: I got the answer, But there is key user in second index.  I had to json parse it before destructuring it

Comment: Sweet, if the answer is correct, you should give one of them an acceptance to close the Q @sumitkhatrii

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the data you actually posted at the bottom of your Q, it would be a simple dereference:

```js
const logg = {"success":true,"user":{"avatar":{"public_id":"avatars/laqmzy3nuqa5vl7awprh","url":"https://res.cloudinary.com/randomID/image/upload/v1659523730/avatars/laqmzy3nuqa5vl7awprh.jpg"},"_id":"62ea5294ff799046c8173fef","name":"sumit khatri","email":"ss@sss.com","password":"$2a$10$nSK2JqUSCdVGIVVBzo1IDerU3jrNFfHRDBESV0Ql6y.vWohZiugEG","role":"admin","createdAt":"2022-08-03T10:48:52.355Z","__v":0},"token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYyZWE1Mjk0ZmY3OTkwNDZjODE3M2ZlZiIsImlhdCI6MTY1OTUyNzM1NCwiZXhwIjoxNjU5OTU5MzU0fQ.TLJYRAm83qQuLVhVkIqYK0u7WetCm9Hn376VvEPX1Ig"};
const user = logg.user;
console.log(user);
```

But if it's still in string form like Alaa said, then you need to do:

```js
const logg = '{"success":true,"user":{"avatar":{"public_id":"avatars/laqmzy3nuqa5vl7awprh","url":"https://res.cloudinary.com/randomID/image/upload/v1659523730/avatars/laqmzy3nuqa5vl7awprh.jpg"},"_id":"62ea5294ff799046c8173fef","name":"sumit khatri","email":"ss@sss.com","password":"$2a$10$nSK2JqUSCdVGIVVBzo1IDerU3jrNFfHRDBESV0Ql6y.vWohZiugEG","role":"admin","createdAt":"2022-08-03T10:48:52.355Z","__v":0},"token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYyZWE1Mjk0ZmY3OTkwNDZjODE3M2ZlZiIsImlhdCI6MTY1OTUyNzM1NCwiZXhwIjoxNjU5OTU5MzU0fQ.TLJYRAm83qQuLVhVkIqYK0u7WetCm9Hn376VvEPX1Ig"}';
const user = JSON.parse(logg).user;
console.log(user);
```

Answer (score 2):

The item is in string format try JSON parsing it `const {user}=JSON.parse(yourString)`